# Different Methods for Fetching Data from Website Android

Tags: android, json

## Greetings to All,

I know that we can fetch data from website and parse it Using JSON Parsing in android. But i would like to know what are the alternatives to fetch data from website and little comparison would be grateful.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using [**Square's Retrofit**](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to fetch any data (and great xml/json and GSON support) from serverside. also, check out **Jsoup** if you want to download html data and parse it easily.

**EDIT:** This is an [**AWESOME ARTICLE about consuming APIs on Android**](http://engineering.meetme.com/2014/03/best-practices-for-consuming-apis-on-android/) covering Retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative I know of is by using GSON.

Provide easy to use mechanisms like toString() and constructor (factory method) to convert Java to JSON and vice-versa.
Allow pre-existing unmodifiable objects to be converted to and from JSON.
Allow custom representations for objects.
Support arbitrarily complex object.
Generate compact and readability JSON output .

Here's a link with a bit more detailed information on GSON: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide